# Passing Multipe Rest Parameters from HTML function Call to TypeScript Function In Angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an Angular2 project in which I am trying to construct an object with an unknown number of parameters from an HTML button click which calls a function. This function is using rest parameters in order to accept an unknown number of parameters as shown below:

```
addArguments(...args: any[]) {
    for (var i = 0, arg; arg = args[i]; i++) {
        console.log("add values args:", ...arg);
    }
}
```

This function is called from an HTML button class as below:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" (click)="addArguments(6, 'Argument1', 'Argument2')">
     Add
</button>
```

The problem is, when I run this code, the console output is `add values args: 6`.

I cannot figure out why it is not passing through the additional 'Argument1' and 'Argument2'.

Comment: I don't know what you meant to do with that for loop but here's a working plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/mj1xNPJU1rwFQVZHZIaM?p=preview

Comment: Found the issue was passing in ...args versus args in a subsequent function call. ...args must be used to continue to pass the separated parameters to another function which also accepts ...args.

Answer (score 1):

You're not constructing the `for` loop correctly.

Should be:

```
addArguments(...args: any[]){
    for (var i = 0, i < args.length; i++) {
        console.log("arg:", args[i]);
    }

    console.log("args:", args); // [6, "Argument1", "Argument2"]
}
```

Comment: The construction is not incorrect. This assigns and the argument in the loop. I found the issue was passing of args instead of ...args.